# Updating a document using mongoose throws range error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a update function in node.js with mongoose ODM like this:

```
var dataObj = req.body;
var id = dataObj.id;  
var updateDetails = function (data) {
            models.bookingConf.update({_id: id}, data, function (err, rows) {
                console.log(err);
                if (!err) {
                    res.send(dataObj);
                }
            });
        };
```

This always throws:

> [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

When I did console.log(data), i got this:

```
{ contact: 
   { _id: 538ca3e612f259a82a000002,
     company: 'Some company',
     contactGroup: 538249fd7c8bc4e94c000003,
     firstName: 'name',
     lastName: 'lastname',
     email: 'test@asdf.com',
     address: '',
     city: '',
     state: '',
     zip: '',
     country: '',
     website: '',
     skypeHandle: '',
     bankAccountNumber: '',
     bankAccountName: '',
     __v: 0,
     directDial: { country: '', area: '', number: '' },
     mobile: { country: '', area: '', number: '' },
     fax: { country: '', area: '', number: '' },
     telephone: { country: '', area: '', number: '' },
     people: [] },
  reference: '',
  carrierReference: '',
  poNumber: '',
  carrier: '',
  vessel: '',
  flight: '',
  origin: '',
  loadingPort: '',
  destination: '',
  finalDestination: '',
  cutOffDate: '2014-06-02T16:17:00.000Z',
  departureDate: '2014-06-01T18:30:00.000Z',
  arrivalDate: '2014-06-01T18:30:00.000Z',
  earliestPickupDate: '2014-06-01T18:30:00.000Z',
  earliestReturnDate: '2014-06-01T18:30:00.000Z',
  latestReturnDate: '2014-06-01T18:30:00.000Z',
  items: [],
  __v: 0,
  date: '2014-06-01T18:30:00.000Z' }
```

**EDIT : FULL CODE**

```
app.put('/api/booking-confirmation-document/*', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
        var dataObj = req.body;
        var id = dataObj.id;
        delete dataObj.id;
        var tasks = [];
        var updateDetails = function (data) {
            models.bookingConf.update({_id: id}, data, function (err, rows) {
                console.log(err);
                if (!err) {
                    res.send(data);
                }
            });
        };
        if (dataObj.contact) {
            tasks.push(function (callback) {
                models.contact.find({_id: dataObj.contact}, function (err, data) {
                    dataObj['contact'] = data[0];
                    callback(null);
                });
            });
        }
        if (dataObj.returnLocation) {
            tasks.push(function (callback) {
                models.contact.find({_id: dataObj.returnLocation}, function (err, data) {
                    dataObj['returnLocation'] = data[0];
                    callback(null);
                });
            });
        }
        if (dataObj.emptyPickupAddress) {
            tasks.push(function (callback) {
                models.contact.find({_id: dataObj.emptyPickupAddress}, function (err, data) {
                    dataObj['emptyPickupAddress'] = data[0];
                    callback(null);
                });
            });
        }
        if (tasks.length > 0) {
            async.parallel(tasks, function (err, callback) {
                updateDetails(dataObj);
            });
        }
        else {
            updateDetails(dataObj);
        }
    });
```

**DATABASE SCHEMA**

```
module.exports.bookingConf = Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    cutOffDate: Date,
    departureDate:Date,
    arrivalDate:Date,
    latestReturnDate:Date,
    earliestReturnDate:Date,
    earliestPickupDate:Date
}, {strict: false});
```

Comment: Do you have a custom validator defined for this model?

Comment: Could you share a little more of your code? Perhaps where updateDetails gets called. Also if you google "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" there are lots of SO hits - were none of them helpful?

Comment: none of them were helpful! See my edit : I have included the full code.

Comment: @veNerd What is the definition of your Mongoose model for this case? Can you share that?

Comment: Have you double checked for circular references or an infinite loop in the code you aren't showing us? That's kinda the first thing that comes to mind with the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. Nothing is jumping out at me from the code you shared.

Comment: @RayStantz there is nothing else to be honest. The code i shared uses async module for populating the data in parallel. nothing else.